# Get values and ID of dynamically generated textfields in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which is being dynamically populated, each row contains two textfields which can be edited. When the user click the save button, i want to read al those entered values and updated accordingly:

```
echo "<td><input value='".$row[0]."' type='hidden'>$sql1[0]</td><td>$sql1[1]</td>
    <td><input type='text' id='disc-".$row[0]."' value='".$row[3]."'></td>
```

The `$row[0]` is the ID of that row in the database and `$row[3]` is the value currently stored. What i am trying to achieve is that once the user clicks save, i read the value entered by the user in the textfield based on the ID so that it can be updated. For that have a javascript that selects those elements:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('#order_basket [id |= "disc"]').length; i++) {
    alert($('#order_basket [id|="disc"]')??.val());
}
```

Now the length returned is correct but i am trying to read in the id and the value which will be further stored in an array.

NOTE: there are more than 1 textfields in the same row, the other textfield has the `id='disc-".$row[0]."'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var values = {};
$('#order_basket input[id^="disc"]').each(function(){
     values[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

Now `values` object will contain id/value pair of each of the input elements

Note that I am using attribute starts with selector `^=` to find all the input elements

Update based on OP's comment.

```
var ids = [], values = [];
$('#order_basket input[id^="disc"]').each(function(){
     ids.push(this.id);
     values.push(this.value);
});
```

Comment: That does help, but just to make it clear, does it mean:
`values[1] = 23` where 1 is the id and 23 is the value?

Comment: `values` is not an array but object. You can use it like value["1"] which will give you `23` which is the value of input element with id `1`.

Comment: How can store all of it in separate arrays? Like id[] and values[]?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use class names:

```
<td><input type='text' class="field1" id='disc-".$row[0]."' value='".$row[3]."'></td>
```

You can then query this out using:

```
   alert($('.field1').val())
```

or:

```
alert($('.field1').attr('id')
```

You can check if there's more then one (because class names do not need to be unique)

```
alert($('.field1').length)
```

Then you can loop through the values using a for loop or .each()